# RVM ruby 1.8.7 running debugger fails when starting web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When using RVM with ruby 1.8.7 I am unable to run the debugger.  I am using rails 2.3.9 and mongrel

script/server --debugger

returns:
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'

this is what my gem list looks like:
ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `rvm` configured correctly?

Run `which gem` to check you are using the `rvm` version of `gem`. When you run `gem install ruby-debug`, what happens?

Check the permissions on the files/folders in your `$GEM_HOME` as well to make sure they are readable by you - I've had problems with gems being installed as root read-only before.

**Edit**

Try running `sudo ./script/server --debugger` to make sure it isn't a permissions issue.

Can you debug a basic ruby script successfully?

```
$ cat test.rb
#!/path/to/ruby
debugger
puts 'Hello world'
$ rdebug /path/to/test.rb
```

Can you run `rdebug ./script/server`?

Comment: which gem:../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/gem
gem install ruby-debug: Successfully installed ruby-debug-0.10.3

I also have read permissions on all those folders

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo with RVM, if you need to sudo on a ruby action with RVM installed, you'll want to use `rvmsudo`

Comment: sudo ./script/server --debugger works
Is that still using rvm 1.8.7 or is it using rvm system?
I can get it to work using rvm system already

Comment: Oops, yeah using `sudo` would use system gems. Could you run the debugger over a script (ie outside of the Rails framework)?